# google app engine dev_appserver.py super slow

Tags: google-app-engine

Even with a simple app like HelloWorld, every time I make a change on the code, and make a new request, the server take like 1-2 minutes to response.  However, http://localhost:8000 responds immediately every time.

Anybody know why and how to resolve this?

Comment: Please clarify. Both 'dev_appserver.py super slow' and 'http://localhost:8000' responds immediately can't both be true. Where exactly are you seeing it take 1-2 minutes to respond? Starting dev_appserver.py? The first request?

Comment: 8000 is the default admin port.  The admin server works just fine.  However, my app on port 8080 takes about 2 minutes to load.

The first request then every time I change the app.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that I might have done wrong is install the go sdk a while back.

Comment: Have you put some logging in.  For instance if your using python in your app_config.py which is loaded before you code.

Comment: I am a python newbie so I am not sure how to do that with google's app engine.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: there is a file monitoring service which checks if any of the app's files were changed and reloads the entire app code in such case,  it could explain the extra delay when files are changed (if the delay is seen only when app files are changed) - this is only applicable to the development server.

Comment: Having the same experience. I make a simple code change, and my refresh of the website hangs for 1-minute (not exaggerating) before serving the updates. It is fast in responding after that, until I make another code change.

Comment: FYI: I gave up.  Guess google really didnt want me to use it.